# What is the effect of having the bayonet attached?

Tags: red-orchestra

In Red Orchestra, it is possible to attach a bayonet to certain rifles. Why is it even an option to not have it attached? Does the bayonet adversly affect the shooting characteristics of the weapon?

Comment: if I made the game, the bayonet would have added weight to the gun, making it more stable in shots... anyway, bayonets are meant for poking, not shooting -- just saying.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual for Red Orchestra: Ostfront 41-45, attaching the bayonet *affects* your accuracy. What does this mean? It likely depends on the weapon you're firing, and you may want to do a bit of real-world research on it.

For instance, Russian "icepick" bayonets attach directly to the barrel of the Mosin-Nagant, which changes how the barrel vibrates during and after discharge. All Russian rifles were sighted-in at the factory with the bayonet attached, so **it is actually in your best interest** **to leave the bayonet attached, even at long distance,** assuming you're shooting a Russian rifle. I don't know about German rifles; ostensibly, the bayonet should have less of an effect on their accuracy. I have *heard* that the Karabiner is less accurate with the bayonet on, since they were supposed to be sighted-in without bayonet fixed. I don't have any confirmation on this though.

Also, bayonets **increase your weapon sway,** due to the added weight.

Answer (score -1):

Its an attachment so you can turn it on or off once you get it, its used more for quick melee kills in the game. It doesn't really change the shooting characteristics of the weapon although there are other attachments that do. Hope this helps!

Comment: "Once I get it"? "Other attachments"? Have I missed something or are you assuming I'm referring to Red Orchestra *2*? In 1, I had the bayonet from the start with supported weapons and the only other attachment I have seen mentioned in the key binding config menu is the MG barrel which is incompatible with bolt-action rifles :)